# How to calculate Total value of of an ARGB image?

Tags: c#, image-processing

How can I calculate Total of an Image; the overall total of all elements.

The source Image is ARGB format, Each color channel can be treated as single 2D matrix. Is this approach right?

Pseudo code:

> `Total[ImageData[img],2] (*Mathematica code*)`

Below is the C# code I have tried; However, I dont understand how to convert the Byte value to Real in C#. Real is Double data type in C#.

```
// Calculate total of Image; Total[ImageData[img]];
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, MskImg3G.Width, MskImg3G.Height);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                MskImg3G.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, MskImg3G.PixelFormat);
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
                int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * MskImg3G.Height;
                byte[] TotalValues = new byte[bytes];

                // Copy the RGB values into the array.
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, TotalValues, 0, bytes);

                // do something with the array
                //Console.WriteLine(rgbValues.Length);
                int sum = 0; foreach (byte b in TotalValues) sum += b;
                Console.WriteLine(sum);//Total[ImageData[img, "Byte"], 2]
                double vOut = Convert.ToDouble(sum);//Byte value - original ImageType - Real(MMA type)
                Console.WriteLine(vOut);//Total[ImageData[img, "Byte"], 2]

                // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(TotalValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
                MskImg3G.UnlockBits(bmpData);
//-------------------------TEST----------------------------------//
```

Both the console line outputs give: 2774762 is the Byte value, how can I get its Double(real) value?

```
> 2774762
> 2774762
```

How can achieve this in C# ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Double(real) value"? What are you expecting from the second output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the image :

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Temp\\img.bmp", true);
```

Get and process the pixels:

```
for for (int i=0;i<bitmap .Height;i++) for (int j=0;j<bitmap .width;j++) 
{
  Color c=bitmap .GetPixel(i,j) ;
  // Do your totalisation(s) here using c.R, c.G and c.B
}
```

Comment: Yes this is also one method of doing it, the problem is with the type of result. I require a Double type (Real Number) result from this operation. Please see the edited code.

Comment: What's wrong with your instruction "double vOut = Convert.ToDouble(sum)" ?

Comment: Gives the same result : 2774762. For both "sum" and "Vout".

Comment: To see up to 6 decimal digits of vOut,  do Console.WriteLine(vOut.ToString("0.000000")); You will get "2774762.000000"